# how to reach outside parent div in jquery $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse in">
    <li  id="parent-menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?= $model->idmain ?>" class="collapsed">
        <a href="?r=catalog/category&route=<?= $model->idmain ?>"> 
            <?= $model->main_category_name ?>
        </a> 
        <span class="arrow"></span>
    </li>
    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="<?= $model->idmain ?>">
        <!-- wanna change this -->
        <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#abc<?= $modelsub->idsubcategory ?>">
            <a href="?r=catalog/sub-category&route=<?= $model->idmain ?>&routes=<?= $modelsub->idsubcategory ?>">
                sub_category_name ?>
            </a>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="abc<?= $modelsub->idsubcategory ?>">
        <li>
            <!-- im here -->
            <a href="?r=catalog/det-category&route=<?= $model->idmain ?>&routes=<?= $modelsub->idsubcategory ?>&router=<?= $modeldet->iddetail ?>"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

```js
 var loc = window.location.href;
$("#menu-content li a").each(function () {
    var status = loc.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) > -1;

    if (status) {

        $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        $(this).closest("ul").addClass( "in" );
        $(this).closest(".sub-menu").prev(".sub-menu").addClass( "in" );
    }
});
```

I want to reach there (the comment typed in my code). I tried with `.parent().find` but it didn't work. I look over the other page and didn't work.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: $(this).parent().prev();

Comment: An UL can't be a child of an UL, so the browser probably changes the markup for you

Comment: aquemini, do an answer ;)

Comment: You don't have class `collapsed`, but `collapse`.

Comment: @ aquemini didnt work sir im in <li>
            <!-- im here -->
            <a href="?r=catalog/det-category&route=<?= $model->idmain ?>&routes=<?= $modelsub->idsubcategory ?>&router=<?= $modeldet->iddetail ?>"></a>
        </li> and wanna change ul that contai my parent (my ul)

Comment: And again, `$(this).closest("ul").find("ul")` probably won't work, as the second UL can't be a direct child of the first UL, it's invalid. Also, you're trying to remove a class that isn't there

Comment: @ adeneo i have update my query. so which way u recommend so i can change the class of ul that contain my ul, because i have to change that class when my link is active. i cant change the design

Comment: There's no way to predict what the HTML will look like, as it's currently totally invalid. Some browser may or may not move that inner UL outside the outer UL to try and fix the mistakes you've done.

Comment: if i give class or even id to the ul that contain my parent ul. is it work?

Comment: Also, where are you "reaching" from, what is `this` in your code ?

Comment: for active class. i update the description sir. it work well for 2lv menu. but for 3 level menu its dont work

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to use .prev() or .closest() without an ID or a className in them. The reason being that your DOM could eventually change, where the tag in the .prev() or .closest() location is no longer mapped to the `<UL>` tag, which you're looking for.

However, you can walk up the DOM & then walk down the DOM to find what you're looking for. So whenever the DOM changes, your code will still be targeting the same `<UL>` tag.

```
$(this).parents('.menu-content').find('.sub-menu')
```

This is more efficient for targeting only 1 tag, as there could be multiple nested .sub-menu class names in the ancestor chain. However, both the closest() and prev() functions must be used. Otherwise, the code won't work. The closest() function can't be used by itself. See this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/b4Lv6mfa/) example, which shows that they are both usable together.

```
$(this).closest("ul").prev("#<?= $model->idmain ?>");
```

Comment: still didnt work sir please help i code like this $(this).parents(".menu-content").find(".sub-menu").addClass( "in" );

Comment: Using `closest()` with a tagname or other identifier is just fine. On the other hand, using `parents()` is generally a really bad idea, as it continues searching all the way up to the document level, and could return much more than just the closest matching element, and is less efficient.

Comment: can somebody help me please

Comment: @adeneo It would only do that if parents() didn't contain a selector. Otherwise, it will only travel up to the div with that id/className in it & then travel down from that point. The documentation is at: http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Comment: @antonscie Since you have 2 .sub-menu class names, you'll have to use the ID instead of the class name. So try using .find("<?= $model->idmain ?>") instead of .find(".sub-menu") Here is a jsfiddle, which will highlight the 2nd UL tag when the bottom link is clicked on: https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/b4Lv6mfa/

Comment: @Clomp - did you read that documentation, `parents()` searches all the way up to the document for any matching elements, it doesn't stop when a match is found, that would be `closest()`

Comment: @Clomp adeneo is right. `.closest()` stops at the closest ancestor that matches the selector, `.parents()` returns **all** the ancestors that match the selector. They're only equivalent if don't have nested elements that match the selector, but `.closest` is still more efficient.

Comment: Hey, @adeneo, have you ever seen a valid use case for `.parents()`?

Comment: Ah good point! I tend to use unique IDs & not repeating/duplicate IDs in the ancestor chain. I'll edit my example to show the most efficient way of using the ID with closest, so that it will still target the correct UL tag: .closest('#<?= $model->idmain ?>') & not just the previous tag. That would still keep antonscie's code from breaking, if another tag is injected in between the original 2 tags.

Comment: @Barmar - Nope, not really. I never use it, but I supposed it *one wanted* to actually search the entire DOM tree upwards, it could be useful ?

Comment: And it doesn't really matter what you use with invalid markup, there's just no way to tell where those inner UL's are, most likely the browser moves them out, and there are no matching parents.

Comment: The example & jsfiddle code have been updated. I noticed that .closest() wouldn't work by itself, without chaining .prev(). I've used .parents().find() before, as it's documented on this page, but .closest() & .prev() aren't: http://api.jquery.com/parent/ So it's easy to find out about the .parents() function, but one has to read the entire jQuery API function list to find the other 2: http://api.jquery.com So the 1st code example works for beginners & the 2nd code example works for power users.

Answer (score 0):

`.closest()` is what you are looking for:

```
$(this).closest('ul');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `$(this).parent().parent().prev();` because your `this` in this case is referring to the anchor. If you're looking to get the `<li>` under `<!-- wanna change this -->`, then you want something like:

```
$(this).parent().parent().prev().find('li').first();
```

Comment: i typle like this $(this).parent().parent().prev().addClass( "in" );and still didnt work sir